# P/Invoke vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures Access Violation

Tags: c#, pinvoke, vulkan

I'm working on a Vulkan wrapper for C# (like I'm sure many people are) and I'm having a bit of a problem with `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures` it either doesn't return data, or throws Access Violations

#### Unanaged Side - Signature:

The signature from the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures.html) is this:

```
void vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(
    VkPhysicalDevice                            physicalDevice,
    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures*                   pFeatures);
```

[`VkPhysicalDevice`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/blob/1.0/src/vulkan/vulkan.h) is a `handle` object defined as:

```
#define VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(object) typedef struct object##_T* object;
VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(VkPhysicalDevice)
```

This is just a pointer and other imports using `IntPtr` or `SafeHandle` wrappers for objects of this shape work.

#### Managed Side - DLL Import:

Expected DLL Import (but failing):

```
[DllImport("vulkan-1.dll", EntryPoint = "vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures")]
internal static extern void GetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(PhysicalDeviceHandle physicalDevice, ref IntPtr features);
```

This is similar to other working imports. Note: `PhysicalDeviceHandle` is derived from `SafeHandle` should be marshalled to `IntPtr`, I have other imports with this pattern that work. The above throws an access violation when called.

---

#### Platform:

- Windows 10 (x64)
- Nvidia Driver: `356.43-vkonly` (latest)

---

#### Update

@V. Kravchenko was [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35594661/471810)

There was nothing wrong with the import above. My issue was actually with the [`vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices.html) call.

First off I had the import wrong, the correct import looks like:

```
[DllImport("vulkan-1.dll", EntryPoint = "vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices ")]
internal static extern Result EnumeratePhysicalDevices (InstanceHandle instance, ref physicalDeviceCount, IntPtr[] physicalDevices);
```

Second off, I was actually using the function incorrectly. You need to call `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` twice. The first call gets the count of devices, the second call populates the array of devices.:

```
IntPtr[] devices = new IntPtr[]();
uint deviceCount = 0;
// populates deviceCount with the number of devices
Vk.EnumeratePhysicalDevices(instanceHandle, ref deviceCount, null);
// populates the devices array with the handle to each device, will only populate up to deviceCount devices
Vk.EnumeratePhysicalDevices(instanceHandle, ref deviceCount, devices);
```

*Note*: this is outlined in the description/valid usage section of the function's documentation, I just didn't interpret it correctly on the first read through.

Once I finally had the right handle values from `EnumeratePhysicalDevices` then my final call to `GetPhysicalDeviceFeatures` worked as expected. The final import for `GetPhysicalDeviceFeatures` looks like:

```
[DllImport("vulkan-1.dll", EntryPoint = "vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures")]
internal static extern void GetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(PhysicalDeviceHandle physicalDevice, ref VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures features);
```

*Note*: any variable with `Handle` in the name is a subclass of [`SafeHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `IntPtr`, which actually does point to a valid object, but not just `IntPtr`. Access violation means that code in dll is trying to access memory, that your `IntPtr` points and can't, because your `IntPtr` doesn't point to a valid object.

Overall, you should use your expected variant, but pass pointer to a valid object.
Working variant is working, because `ref IntPtr` is actually a pointer to IntPtr, and IntPtr object's location, to which `ref IntPtr` is pointing, is valid memory.

Comment: I noticed the pointer to a pointer thing earlier and updated the prompt. However besides that, I think you're suggesting that the values I have for `IntPtr physicalDevice` might not point to valid objects? Seems like a good place to start looking.

Comment: @klyd Function is failing to read (or to write) memory, to which your pointers point, so yes, they are invalid.

Comment: @klyd `features` must point to memory large enough to hold enough int32s as there are bool32 in [this structure](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/xhtml/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures) (55)

Comment: @ratchetfreak I did have that structure already setup, but tried returning a pointer instead to rule out issues marshaling to the structure. V. Kravchenko was correct, the pointers I was passing to the function were wrong, not the function itself.